# Correspondence between eigenvectors and eigenvalues

Tags: list-manipulation

Let us say I have a matrix `h` (2x2). Now, I want to get the eigenvectors and eigenvalues of my matrix `h`:

```
Eigenvectors[h]={v,u}={{v1,v2},{u1,u2}}
Eigenvalues[h]={ev,eu}
```

Are you sure that ALWAYS,the eigenvalue corresponding to `v` is gonna be `ev` and never `eu`? Does Mathematica always respect the order, or it might happen that it mixes the order?

Comment: No, there is no guarantee that, if done separately, the orders will correspond. To get this guarantee you should use `Eigensystem`.

Comment: not necessarily, use `{evals,evecs}=Eigensystem[h]`